# Forbidden You don't have permission to access a Django site

Tags: django, apache

I followed the Django docs and edited apache2.conf with this setup,

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /path/to/mysite.com

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory
```

but when I access mysite.com I get this error.

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at www.mysite.com Port 80

I'm on a VPS.

Comment: I had a similar problem recently and it turned out it was a permissions issue related to the fact that I pointed Apache to my private folders with my django project. When I copied the project to /var/www/html , which is the default location on my system where Apache looks for stuff to display when you go to 127.0.0.1, this particular problem disappeared -- how about you try something similar? (remember to edit the Apache conf file!)

Comment: Django site should run on any directory